# I am unable to add the <script> tag to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am integrating Postpay payment system with my web application by adding JS code to the HTML page, but nothing works.

Here is the code I need to integrate:

```
<script>
        window.postpayAsyncInit = function() {
          postpay.init({
            merchantId: '{merchantId}',
            sandbox: true,
            theme: 'light',
            locale: 'en'
          });
        };
</script>
    
<script async src="https://cdn.postpay.io/v1/js/postpay.js"></script>
```

I used this [tutorial](https://ui.postpay.io/quickstart).

I'm a backender and don't know JS, nothing works for me. How can I get this to work?

This is the console output, there are 2 exceptions:

[image]

Comment: Check the console. Any errors, like `"init" of undefined is not a function`, or `cannot call "init" of undefined`?

Comment: because your script  is async maybe  it load later. put <script async src="https://cdn.postpay.io/v1/js/postpay.js"></script> first then put other code

Comment: Hi @Salame
If you want to integrate a postpay.
1. Try with sandbox account & enable the sandbox mode to true
2. Then, we need to get the merchant from your postpay account
3. The code, which you added nothing will do. First, you need to add the product widget details & amount all the required information for payment. Then only this script will execute

Comment: I found 2 exceptions in the console and added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @foadabdollahi, when I moved the line <script async src = "cdn.postpay.io/v1/js/postpay.js"> </script>, nothing happened.

Comment: @Plutus, Thanks for the comment. For example: I changed {merchantId} to my merchantId and changed sandbox to true, what else do I need to do? Where can I use a sandbox account? How do I add the product widget details and the amount of all required billing information?

Comment: You showed the issues tab. You need to look at the console tab. Being a backender like you claim I would've kinda expected you're familiar with how debugging works?

Comment: @connexo, Console output is empty.

Comment: @Salame, Could you brief your question with more details [With code]. That would be easy for us to help you out

Comment: @Salama Well the issues tab tells you exactly what is the problem, and explains it in detail, along with instructions how to fix it. It even has a *Learn more* link, which I assume you've studied thoroughly. What exactly  are you missing there?

Comment: @Connexo When adding {merchantId} and sandbox = true, the errors disappeared.

Comment: @Plutus, My code hasn't changed, I only changed sandbox = true. You've written about the sandbox account, product widget details, and billing information. Do I need to add these parameters as arguments to the code? If so, how can I specify them?

Answer (score 0):

If the first script relies on the script from the cdn link, the latter should be placed first in order like below:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.postpay.io/v1/js/postpay.js"></script>
<script>
        window.postpayAsyncInit = function() {
          postpay.init({
            merchantId: '{merchantId}',
            sandbox: false,
            theme: 'light',
            locale: 'en'
          });
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work for me. I copied this code from the documentation. Most likely, I was mistaken somewhere else.